# 3-4 point joseki - wide double-pincer

Tags: go, joseki

After a low approach at W2, B3 is a wide pincer.  I double-pincered at W4 and then diagonal B5.

```
$$
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . 4 . . |
$$ . . . . . . . 5 . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . 1 . . |
$$ . . 3 . . . 2 . 6 . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ ----------------------
```

In the follow-up I to W14, after B15 is the marked stone I wound up with only one eye.

```
$$Bm7
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . 8 . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . O . . |
$$ . . . . . . . X . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . 7 X 5 . |
$$ . . X . . . O 3 O 1 . |
$$ . . . . . B . 6 4 2 . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ ----------------------
```

What was a better follow-up to the original joseki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be simple - don't play at 14 in your final diagram. Instead, try this:

```
$$Bm7
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . O . . |
$$ . . . . . . . B . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . 7 X 5 . |
$$ . . X . 8 . O 3 O 1 . |
$$ . . . . . . . 6 4 2 . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ ----------------------
```

Note how white is alive, while black has an empty triangle, a bad shape in this case. It is not easy for black to attack the white stone on the right side. For instance:

```
$$
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . 1 . . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . 2 O . . |
$$ . . . . . . . X . . . |
$$ . . . . . . . X X X . |
$$ . . X . O . O X O X . |
$$ . . . . . . . O O O . |
$$ . . . . . . . . . . . |
$$ ----------------------
```

If B1, white can split at 2. If B1 at 2, white can move fluently to the right side by playing at 1 herself. In the meantime, black has no eyes yet.

In the original diagram, B13 might be a bad move. I don't know this joseki, but I'd guess black should try something else instead, possibly before 13.

Answer (score 0):

With a counterpincer, you need to think about sacrificing one stone or the other. One way is to play 14 as in mafuctct's answer, and "let go" of the stone on the right side.

The other way is to extend one or more spaces to the left of 4, and sacrifice the 2 stone. But since Black played a wide pincer, you should probably develop the 2 stone instead of counterpincering.